# Jenkins Pipeline variable with node scope

Tags: variables, jenkins, groovy, scope

for our jenkins pipeline environment we are implementing a function library.
This library we want to use on multiple nodes. For some logging functionality I am looking for a way to  have variables with a "node scope".

this means the library function (in the minimal example below say()) should have a different output depending on the node

```
g_str_test = "test"

parallel firstBranch: {
    node {
        echo g_str_test // = test
        l_str_test = "para1"
        echo l_str_test
        sleep 2
        l_str_test = "paraaaa11"
        g_str_test = "para1"
        say() // = paraaaa11

    }
}, secondBranch: {
    node {
        echo g_str_test
        l_str_test = "para2"
        echo l_str_test // = para2
        sleep 5
        echo "l: "+l_str_test // should be para2 !!!!!! (but is paraaaa11)
        echo "g: "+g_str_test //= para1
        say() // = para2 !!!!!!
    }
},
failFast: true

def say(){
    echo "say: "+l_str_test
}
```

is there a way to have groovy variables with a defined scope

```
node{
[VALID HERE -- also known in called functions]
}
[UNKNOWN HERE]
```

when using "def l_str_test" for each node l_str_test is not known in say()

I know a solution would be to just pass the variable when calling the function. But in reality there are many variables I would have to pass to each function which will make the code look really ugly.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the variable prepending `def`. Here you have an example failing in the second `echo` step:

```
node {
    def var = 'hello'
    echo "$var"
}

node {
    echo "$var"
}
```

Comment: using a def  I already tried. The problem with that is that it won't work with functions called inside the node (not without passing the variable)